# A feature to select a Table(from the list of tables from Database) in Filter

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Tableau dashboard for some counts over the period of time. I need to filter this dashboard for multiple tables from database.

Let say I have 5 tables in database (with no relation between them), how do I dynamically select each table in published dashboard.

As such I can have 5 different tabs on single dashboard but I may have 50 tables to filer on, hence not feasible or ideal to publish 50 different tabs.

Please suggest any idea.

Thanks

Expected Results- 
Should have a filter option on Tableau Dashboard which should filter the dashboard for different tables from database.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for. Are you using the many tables to drive the data in the dashboard? Check out unions and see if that's what you're looking for https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-gb/union.htm

Comment: @tim- Yes different tables but they do not have matching columns. 
and I have multiple tables (around 50 now and may grow in no in future)